# Add items to a list in the a model that contains multiple lists in ASP.Net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, forms, list, asp.net-mvc-2, model

Ok, so this one has had me stumped for a few hours today. After trying to muster up a couple solutions, I can't seem to get it just right.

I have a model, which contains some primitive properties and some lists.

In the view, I need to be able to update any one of these lists (add / remove / update) without hitting the database and saving the changes. The save action will only happen when the save button is clicked on the page. There will be multiple forms on the page.

The forms are as follows....

The main form will just have name/description fields. 
The other forms will contain the fields needed for the types in the lists.

Example Model

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Type1> { get; set; }
    public List<Type2> { get; set; }
    public List<Type3> { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend looking HTML produced and write client side script to update HTML or use [ajax](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/contact-manager/iteration-7-add-ajax-functionality-cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more failed attempts, I decided to do it this way:

I throw the Model into a Session variable. Then in the view I have two forms, one for each list. The forms submit to an action that retrieves the model from the session variable, inserts the record to the appropriate list, and returns the same view with the updated model.

Since using AJAX isn't a requirement, this works just how i need it to.